# Was a 37,000-year-old elephant-skin drum found in the Antarctic?

Tags: history

I was searching information about drums skins made of animal hide and I thought, "has there ever been a drum made with elephant skin?".

When I googled this I keep finding multiple links that say, that the oldest drum ever was found by archeologists, trapped in the ice of Antarctica. and is supposably 37,000 years old and made of elephant skin.

Example from [the book *Drums* by Roberta Baxter](https://www.cengage.com/search/productOverview.do;jsessionid=DAC8AE38E8DD3169927423255E94A1E8?N=197%204294892090%204294966035&Ntk=P_EPI&Ntt=1195348903185954248620200811204525469&Ntx=mode%2Bmatchallpartial) (2020). The "Look inside" preview visible on that website contains this page:

[image]

I see multiple sites claim this but, I cannot find any source to this and doubt that this is real. Does anyone know where this story came from?

Comment: @hdhondt [Avery](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/22367/avery) found a book which makes that claim and posted an image. I made an edit to add a link to a website where the book can be previewed. The preview contains the image posted by Avery. My edit is currently pending review.

Comment: Before someone else reverse-image-searches the photo from the mentioned book which appears on the same page as the image in the question: It is not the supposed 37,000 year old drum but [a stock photo of the also mentioned 2,500 year old Vietnamese bronze drum](https://www.alamy.com/stock-image-miniature-drum-with-four-frogs-ca-500-bcad-300-162363038.html).

Comment: Curious graphic.  The "Vietnam" arrow points to Korea.

Comment: *Science* magazine had an article in 1998 ["Ancient Ruins Found in Antarctica"](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/1998/03/ancient-ruins-found-antarctica) but I suspect it was not entirely accurate

Comment: "Enjoy this 1998 edition of our annual April Fools' Day science story!" It was just a prank.

Comment: I've moved some meta-discussion about whether questions like this are on-topic [to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126641/discussion-on-question-by-avidlistener-was-a-37-000-year-old-elephant-skin-drum).

Comment: When you get multiple hits of the same claim with the identical wording and errors, and little else, the main conclusion is that they all plagiarised one dubious source.

Comment: There were not any elephants (or relatives) or humans anywhere near Antarctica at that time.

Answer (score 2):

This claim originally came from the article [10 Earliest Known Musical Instruments](http://web.archive.org/web/20100413231539/http://www.smashinglists.com/10-earliest-known-musical-instruments/) which was posted to the defunct website "Smashing Lists" in 2010.

> 4. Elephant Skin Drum [37,000 years ago]
>
> The earliest known drum was 30,000 years old when man used animal hide stretched to create sound. The first discovered  is from an elephant skin used since it was preserved from scavenging in Antarctica’s ice age.

As you can see, this earliest statement is not quite grammatical and contradicts itself about age. It offers no citation. The accompanying photo is of a [real elephant skin drum from Vietnam](https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/close-detail-ancient-ceremonial-elephant-skin-195520061), but certainly not a 30,000 year old one.

This list was cited by the book ["The Musical Human" by Michael Spitzer](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2021/apr/03/the-musical-human-by-michael-spitzer-review-a-wide-ranging-global-history-of-music) to support the claim:

> The apparent vestige of an elephant-hide drum has been dated at 37,000 years old.

Comment: How do you know that the top-10 list from "Smashing Lists" is the original source of the claim?